# Using uwp crash logs

Tags: uwp, crash-reports, windows-store

I have an app in the Windows Store. There are some crashes. Microsoft duly reports these crashes in its "health" report. However, I am having a lot of trouble getting useful information into or out of these reports. For example, the stack trace is often empty. Or it might look like this:

```
0   Jockusch_Calculator_WindowsStore        0xF40290
1   Jockusch_Calculator_WindowsStore        0x1083845
2   Jockusch_Calculator_WindowsStore        0x1083000
3   Jockusch_Calculator_WindowsStore        0x108F896
4   Jockusch_Calculator_WindowsStore        0xF1243A
5   Jockusch_Calculator_WindowsStore        0xBA1002
6   Jockusch_Calculator_WindowsStore        0x106A531
7   Jockusch_Calculator_WindowsStore        0xD5F252
8   Jockusch_Calculator_WindowsStore        0xD4A572
9   SharedLibrary   System::Action$1_System::IntPtr_.Invoke 0xE
10  Jockusch_Calculator_WindowsStore        0xF98B3D
11  Jockusch_Calculator_WindowsStore        0xF9EC3D
12  Jockusch_Calculator_WindowsStore        0xD383AE
13  Jockusch_Calculator_WindowsStore        0xD7A36C
14  Jockusch_Calculator_WindowsStore        0xD7A4E2
```

Those hex strings are "Offsets" Is there a way to turn them into method names or some other useful information?

Alternatively, I could catch the crashes with an error handler. In the error handler, I could use the caught exception to compute a string containing actual useful information, such as a stack trace with method names. If I do that, is there a way to embed that string into the crash report I will see in the "health" portion of analytics?

Comment: Did you upload the pdb's when created the appx package?

Comment: When I build for the store, the checkbox "Include full symbol files, if any, to enable crash analytics for the app" is checked. I only submit the single .appxupload file and don't know how to look inside it to see if it contains symbols.

Comment: Hi William, The best practice for you is to contact Dev Center Support(http://aka.ms/storesupport) through your developer account for professional suggestion. Thanks.